# Вернуть массив из ф-ции

Tags: c++-cli

Как массиву  Arr присвоить значение которое возвращается из функции ?

```
 *Arr = In_Out(mass); //вызов ф-ции



 char* In_Out(char* In) {
char Out[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

//char In [8]= { 0x73,0xbe,0x3c,0xff,0xdb,0x77,0x00,0xAA};

char x, y, z;

int o = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    BYTE l = In[j];
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {

        if ((7 - j - i) >= 0) 
        {
            x = 0x01 << (7 - j);
            y = l << (7 - j - i);

            Out[7 - i] = Out[7 - i] | (y & x);
        }

        else
            Out[7 - i] = Out[7 - i] | (  (l >> ( abs(7 - j - i) ) ) & ( 0x01 << (7 - j) )  );

    }
}

return Out;
}
```

Comment: а оно разве не присваивается? Непонятно зачем там звёздочка у `Arr`

Comment: @Komdosh нет не присваивается

Comment: `Out` - локальный массив. Его нельзя передавать наружу. Нужно выделить память под массив в куче и её адрес возвращать. В каждом первом учебнике описано.

Comment: И не лучше ли в C++/CLI использовать управляемые структуры данных, те же массивы?